# How to find min and max of a team based on RANK

Tags: mysql, sql

Question:
List the first and last place teams and their number of at-bats for each year
What would be the SQL query, how can I do min and Max on rank and group results by year in
same column?

Below are the columns of the Teams table on which I am trying to write SQL

Here the columns are explained
Teams Table Columns

```
    yearID         Year
    lgID           League
    teamID         Team
    franchID       Franchise (links to TeamsFranchise table)
    divID          Team's division
    Rank           Position in final standings
    AB             At bats
```

Desired output

I am trying to achieve min and max at ranks for the same year , but unable to figure out
how to get the min max in the rank in the same column

```
   Team ID, Year, Rank, At Bats 
   PH1,     1871,  1,    1281
   RC1,     1871,  9,    1036
   LAA,     2014,  1,    5652
```

Sample Data

```
 yearID lgId    teamID  franchID  divID   Rank    Ab(at-bats)
 '1902', 'AL', 'BOS',   'BOS',     '',    '3',   '4875'
 '1914', 'NL', 'BRO',   'LAD',     '',   '5',   '1386'
 '1925', 'AL', 'CLE',    'CLE',    '',   '6',   '1631'
 '1937', 'NL', 'NY1',    'SFG',    '',    '1',   '1484'
```

MySql Script is Giving me errors

```
select teamID,yearID,Rank,AB, 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY yearID order by Rank DESC) other_rank
from Teams;
```

ERROR

```
   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
   syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY yearID order by Rank DESC) other_
   rank from Teams' at line 1
```

Comment: Can you specify any code that you may have tried?

Comment: Well what I tried was giving me rank min and max in diff columns , it wouldn'tn be of much help here . I know what to do but I don't know how we can do min and max in rank. something like rank over partition won't work here because I guess the rank is already given here .

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output in regards to that sample data. Also, Please tag the correct database that you are using.

Comment: Please don't tag spam; remove the dbms tags that are not relevant to your question.

Comment: @Popeye Using mysql , sample data is provided and desired output the values can vary but if you see the output you will know that we are trying to find min and max by rank for the same year

Comment: @Nick Done, tho I tagged generally the SQL people

Comment: @AdityaVerma thanks - you should only tag SQL questions with the DBMS you want a solution for as queries can be quite different for each type, and it's not fair to users who might answer in a language you're not interested in.

Comment: @Nick can you suggest some answer for my query

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but perhaps a UNION query of the MAX(rank) for a year with the MIN(rank) for the year? Alternatively in PostgreSQL or MySQL 8+ you could use window functions to order the teams according to rank (ascending or descending) and then just select the team with rownumber = 1 for both cases (that will be the team with the highest or lowest rank respectively)

Comment: @Nick so do I have to do a group by on year I guess or no ?

Comment: @AdityaVerma with MIN and MAX you'd need to, not with window functions though.

Comment: @Nick can I use min and max on the same column  rank and get the output as a single column? I think I don't get that very well can you explain a little bit.

Comment: To try and clarify... you want to return the rows that have the MIN and MAX rank for each year (and league, or just year?)? Is the MIN always going to equal 1?

Comment: @NickWyes I want Min and Max rank for each year and yes Min will be one always

Comment: That window function was introduced in MySQL 8.0. Check the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably work:

```
with max_rank as (
    SELECT yearID, max(Rank) as MaxRank
    from Teams
    Group by yearID
)
SELECT T.*
FROM Teams T
LEFT OUT JOIN max_rank M ON T.yearID = M.yearid AND T.rank = m.MaxRank
WHERE T = 1 OR T.rank = M.MaxRank;
```

Comment: so can you explain to me whats happening in last line , the where clause, So like T.Rank =1 or T = 1?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should be "WHERE T.rank = 1 OR T.rank = M.MaxRank;"